# JSON issues with iOS 6

Tags: json, parsing, ios6

I am trying to parse a json which looks like this:

```
[{"category": "anti-social-behaviour", "persistent_id": "", "location_subtype": "", "id": 23193805, "location": {"latitude": "52.6387452", "street": {"id": 883166, "name": "On or near Charnwood Street"}, "longitude": "-1.1136914"}, "context": "", "month": "2013-04", "location_type": "Force", "outcome_status": null}, 
{"category": "anti-social-behaviour", "persistent_id": "", "location_subtype": "", "id": 23195135, "location": {"latitude": "52.6288245", "street": {"id": 883098, "name": "On or near Roslyn Street"}, "longitude": "-1.1106710"}, "context": "", "month": "2013-04", "location_type": "Force", "outcome_status": null},'
```

I am trying to parse it with that way:

```
NSString *url = @"http://data.police.uk/api/crimes-at-location?date=2012-02&location_id=12345";

NSData *jsonDataString = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *error = nil;

NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonDataString options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

 NSArray *myResults = [results valueForKeyPath:@""];

 NSDictionary *bug = (NSDictionary *)[myResults objectAtIndex:0];

// And get its name
NSString *bugName = [bug objectForKey:@"category"];
NSLog(@"%@",bugName);
```

I get error: __NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

So what I should put in valueForKeyPath?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, what more info do you want to get... You're trying to get an object from an empty array. Are you sure your JSON is an array and not an Object?

Comment: Please post **actual code.** What you written in the first line is **not valid JSON.**

Comment: "results" isn't a dictionary.  NSLog it and you will see that it's an array.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Why is that not valid (though truncated) JSON??  It's an array containing two "objects".

Comment: JSON is valid. I valid it using a tool

Comment: (If you simply remove "results" and assign from `jsonObjectWithData` directly to "myResults" you will be pretty close.)

Comment: Everyone:  Please go to json.org and learn how to read JSON.  `[` starts an array.  `{` starts an "object".  That's clearly an array containing two "objects" (with more "objects" presumably truncated).

Comment: Hot Licks has right. But how to read the first object and the category for example?

Comment: @HotLicks If OP is getting his or her JSON through `NSJSONSerialization` at all then it's not what he or she has posted here. There's no point in trying to debug problems with obviously-malformed JSON if that's not even what the OP's problem is.

Comment: @bdesham - What's posted above is perfectly legit (though truncated) JSON, *before* parsing by NSJSONSerialization or whatever.  The OP's problem is assuming an "object" (NSDictionary) when he's got an array.  If you still claim that the above is invalid JSON please explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: @HotLicks In my opinion, "truncated JSON" *is* invalid JSON.

Comment: @bdesham - But truncated JSON is a perfectly good way to represent the JSON being parsed, if the problem occurs prior to the truncation.  Insisting on the entire JSON is like insisting that all 10,000 lines of an app be posted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sigh...

```
NSData *jsonDataString = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *error = nil;

NSArray* myResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonDataString options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}

NSDictionary *bug = (NSDictionary *)[myResults objectAtIndex:0];

// And get its name
NSString *bugName = [bug objectForKey:@"category"];
NSLog(@"%@",bugName);
```

Comment: Still not working. The url is: NSString *url = @"http://data.police.uk/api/crimes-at-location?date=2012-02&location_id=12345";

Comment: @user776720 - That query yields an empty array, so you'll get the array bounds error.  If you drop the date (or change it to 2013-04) you get one vehicle crime.

Comment: My bad I accidentally used the wrong url to test your solution! Thank you